# How can I read an large array of switches with some microcontroller?

Tags: switches, matrix

I have been asked by someone whether or not I could do some programming on a large array (something like 18 x 16) of analogue switches.

I would want to wire up an array of analogue switches (you know, on-off toggle switches) that are in a grid pattern with rows and columns so that I can at a single moment understand the state of all those switches and do something with code on the basis of it.

I realize that microprocessors have limited GPIO's, I would need 288 ports to read that many switches. What is a circuit I can use to reduce the number of ports to something more manageable like less than 48?

Comment: What exactly are these *analog switches*?  Do you mean analog mux?  How are these things different from a array of pushbuttons, for example?  Your description makes little sense.

Comment: *do some programming on a large array of analogue switches* Programmers **program**, those programs can use IO ports. If that array can connect to those IO ports (how is not your concern, you do the **software**, someone else should do the **hardware**) then you can do it. For you as a programmer it does not matter what is connected, be it analog switches, a car, a house or an elephant. As long as they interface with IO ports that **you** can control, you can do it.

Comment: Programming analogue switches *is not the same as* reading an array of switches.

Comment: Depending on switch attribute. like a keyboard encoder except Analog switches, you need a row x column scanner MUX to read each value into a S&H for serialization.  this is exactly how an LCD works except in reverse.  similar to reading a multilevel FLASH EPROM then D/A to binary // bits. where they store 2 or 3 bits per analog flash cell.  So define Z of switch, ON, OFF and capacitance limits then frequency of scan !!!! in your question...  if you can OR define source so we can... capiche?

Comment: Is this analog or just a keyboard encoder? If analog it is called a Crosspoint switch IC's , once used in analog telephony, but obsolete now I think.... nope they exist.. http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Communication-Networking-ICs/Analog-Digital-Crosspoint-ICs/_/N-5cfzo?P=1yyhnmsZ1yyhnce  here's a 16x16 http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/AD75019-877400.pdf

Comment: What you want to do is to scan a [switch matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_matrix_circuit). Nobody calls simple mechanical switches "analogue switches", so people think that you must mean [analog switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogue_switch) (AKA digitally controlled analog signal switch ICs) which makes no sense, hence why your question was put on hold. Replace "analogue" with "mechanical" or nothing at all, and people will understand.

Comment: This must be rewritten to disambiguate the "analogue switch" vs. pushbutton issue. Closing as _unclear_ until then.

Answer (score 2):

For your example of an 18x16 matrix, you will need a maximum of 34 GPIO lines.  One side will be configured as push-pull outputs, and the other as inputs.

Here is a smaller matrix as an example:

[image]

We will use the columns as inputs, and the rows as outputs.  Initially set all of the outputs low.

Configure the column inputs to use internal pull-down resistors, or supply external ones (e.g. 100K).

When reading the matrix, one by one change one of the row pins high.  Then look at the column pins, and see if any are high instead of normally low (due to the pull-downs).

For example, if SW2 is enabled, then Col1 will be high only when Row2 is high.

The diodes prevent feedback when multiple switches are thrown (thanks, Tut).

You can save another 12 pins by using a 4-to-16 line decoder such as the [74HCT7514](http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4514_CNV.pdf) to drive the row outputs, so now you need just 22 GPIO pins to read the 288 switches.

Comment: Since the OP has indicated toggle switches, unless they are momentary and unless only one will be closed at a time, a diode will need to be added to each switch.

Comment: @Tut Thanks, didn't notice the toggle switch requirement.  Updated my example to use diodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your mention of "analog" switches is misleading.  You apparently want to read a array of 18 x 16 toggle switches.  You should have said this up front.

Yes, in the brute force case this would require 288 input lines to the microcontroller.  However, you can do something called *multiplexing*.  Since your switches are physically arranged in a 18 x 16 pattern, and that's close to optimum anyway, you arrange the switches electrically in a X-Y matrix.  This only requires 18 + 16 lines instead of 18 x 16 lines.

Let's say you have 18 columns and 16 rows.  Each of the 18 column wires are connected to one sides of the switches in their column.  The row lines are connected to the other sides of the switches in their row.  Turning on a switch therefore shorts one column line to one row line.

Since 16 is a nice number of bits to read at one time, we'll sequence thru the columns.  Imagine the firmware raising one of the column lines at a time, with weak pulldowns on the row lines.  If a switch is on, it will raise its row line when its column line is activated.  The firmware sequences thru the column lines, and reads the row lines separately for each column.

That's the basic idea, but it doesn't quite work that way electrically, at least not if more than one switch could be on at a time.  Switches work both ways.  If a switch is on, its row line goes high when it's column is activated.  However, any other closed switch on that row now raises its column line, which can raise other row lines, etc.

The solution is to make the switches uni-directional.  This is done by putting a diode in series with each one.  The diode allows a closed switch to raise its row line when its column line is high, but makes it impossible to raise a row line from a high column line, regardless of the switch state.